# Python ftp upload bug: no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: python, bash, file-upload, ftp, getopt

I'm writing an ftp uploader with getopt. If use `fullname = 'file.jpg'` all is okay, but if `fullname = newfiles` not turned and return error notification:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Maybe my app doesn't have a rights to send file?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  

import sys
import getopt
import ftplib
import os

def usage():
    print "Home"
#if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "uhc", ["upload=", "help", "connect"])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)


if opts == []:
    usage()

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
        usage()
    elif opt in ("-u", "--upload"):
        newfile = args
        if not file:
            print "Nie wybrano pliku!"
        else:
            print "Wybrany plik",newfile
            ftp = ftplib.FTP()
            ftp.connect('host')
            ftp.login('user', 'pass')
            ftp.cwd('./')
            print "Wybieram:", ftp.pwd()
            print "Wgrywam"
            fullname = newfile
            name = os.path.split(fullname)[1]
            f = open(fullname, "rb")
            ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + name, f)
            f.close()
            print "OK"

            print "Files:"
            print ftp.retrlines('LIST') 
            ftp.quit()
    elif opt in ("-c", "--connect"):
        print "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your script can work with some modifications. The error is due to passing a list to the os.path.split() function.

I would suggest the following:

According to the [getopt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#module-getopt) documention, options that require an argument should be followed by a colon ":".

Change this line:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "uhc", ["upload=", "help", "connect"])
```

To this (add a colon after the u in your options list):

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "u:hc", ["upload=", "help", "connect"])
```

Then in your for loop, the arg variable will be populated with the filname. Set newfile = arg instead of args.

Change this:

```
    elif opt in ("-u", "--upload"):
        newfile = args
```

To this (arg instead of args):

```
    elif opt in ("-u", "--upload"):
        newfile = arg
```

After the changes, you should be able to run your script with 1 or more files, for example:
your_script.py -u "file1.jpg" -u "file2.jpg"

Also, the following code:

```
if not file:
        print "Nie wybrano pliku!"
    else:
        print "Wybrany plik",newfile
```

The "file" in this case is a python builtin and should always fall into the else condition. Another option might be to check for the existence of the file using [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)(newfile).

Comment: if change uhc to u:hc not turned to my if
if not file:
   print "Nie wybrano pliku!"
  else:
   print "Wybrany plik",file
if empty view usage(), why?

Comment: Please comment with an example of how you call your script. I edited my answer to try and help. Does your "if note file:" statement still match the current code in your question, or has it changed at all?